# Using grepl to filter columns names in specific range of columns

Tags: r

I have a df that contain colnames like this:

```
[1] "lab_id"               "weeks"                "group"      
[4] "level"                "id_row"               "id"                  
[7] "number"               "tube"                 "dp"              
[10] "time"                "label"                "age"                 
[13] "gender"              "wtspike_ab1"         "wtrbd_ab1"          
[16] "wts1_ab1"            "wts2_ab1"             "wtntd_ab2"          
[19] "wtn_ab2"             "alphaspike_ab2"       "alpharbd_ab2"       
[22] "betaspike_ab2"       "betarbd_ab2"          "gammaspike_ab2"
```

My goal is filter this df by column names, using the following approach:

```
test1 <- test[, test <- grepl('wtspike|wtrbd|wts1|wts2|wtntd|wtn', colnames(test))]
```

This works filtering the `colnames` that not match the pattern, which is fine. However, is taking off the metadata columns `1:14`, so I tried to use something like this to avoid perform the operation in the columns `1:14`.

```
filtered_test <- test[, 1:14(test) & grepl('wtspike|wtrbd|wts1|wts2|wtntd|wtn', colnames(test))]
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

My question is related to what alternative can I use to perform the same operation without take the columns `1:14`.

- Is it a better alternative to perform the operation?
- What is wrong in my line that give me that error?

Comment: Your use of `<-` _inside_ of the `[` expression is not right. If your `test` is a frame, then the first time you run `test[, test <- ...]`, it might look like it did something frame-like, but now `test` is a logical vector.

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output in this example? Also it would be easier to test if you provided a `dput(test)` so we can copy/paste the code to test it. When subsetting you can either uses boolean values or indexes, but you can't mix them.

Comment: Perhaps remove `test <-` from the inside and see how it works?

Comment: mimicking your code, if I do `mtcars[, mtcars <- grepl("m|p", colnames(mtcars))]`, that seems to do the filtering correctly, but now `mtcars` is (briefly) `c(T, F, T, T, F, F, F, F, T, F, F)` instead of a frame. However, if (after restoring `mtcars` to its original frame data), we do just `mtcars[, grepl("m|p", colnames(mtcars))]`, we get the subset of columns as expected.

Comment: What is "metadata columns `1:14`"? Are you saying that you want to keep columns `1:14` and all columns that match your `grepl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to keep all columns matching your `grepl` as well as columns 1-14 (whether or not they match). Perhaps this?

```r
mt <- mtcars[1:3,]
mt[, grepl("d|w", colnames(mt))]
#               disp drat    wt
# Mazda RX4      160 3.90 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag  160 3.90 2.875
# Datsun 710     108 3.85 2.320
```

If we also want to keep the first two columns (akin to your `1:14`), then

```r
mt[, replace(grepl("d|w", colnames(mt)), 1:2, TRUE)]
#                mpg cyl disp drat    wt
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 3.90 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 3.90 2.875
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108 3.85 2.320
```

Or another approach (same results)):

```r
mt[, seq_along(mt) %in% 1:2 | grepl("d|w", colnames(mt))]
#                mpg cyl disp drat    wt
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 3.90 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 3.90 2.875
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108 3.85 2.320
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have your data , so i'll use the simple iris frame
you can decide what to drop and what to keep by calculating the names
and doing set operations on them; for example

```
(cn <- colnames(iris))
(drop_by_grep <- cn[grepl('Petal|Sepal',cn)])
(except_not <- cn[1:3]) # the first 3, so we permit to drop the 4th
(therefore_drop <- setdiff(drop_by_grep,except_not)) # the 4th 
(therefore_keep <- setdiff(cn,therefore_drop)) # everything but the 4th
```